# Efficiently skipping Stripe API calls and/or logging for test IDs

Tags: go, logging, stripe-payments

I would like to be able to have test stripe accounts live along production accounts in the same database, but treat them differently depending on whether I am using test API keys.

Currently the stripe Go library logs errors when a test Stripe ID is queried while using production API keys. The Stripe library itself logs this when trying to fetch such a stripe customer:

```
Error encountered from Stripe: {"code":"resource_missing","status":404,"message":
"No such customer: cus_foo; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode
key was used to make this request.","param":"id","request_id":"req_foo","type":
"invalid_request_error"}
```

I would like to avoid having this happen by either doing a separate API call that asks "is this a test user?" or by suppressing only the above error output so I can ignore and not print my own error in the case of test users.

I do the obvious

```golang
params := &stripe.CustomerParams{}
stripeCustomer, err := customer.Get(stripeID, params)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

From a function, but the call to `Get()` has already logged an error before I have a chance to react to it..

I could just have a `test_account` attribute attached to the user, but I'd rather just make a few needless API calls and silently ignore them somehow.

Comment: What is customer here?

Comment: `customer` is the imported stripe library `"github.com/stripe/stripe-go/customer"`.